# How to minimize windows on double-click of the window frame?

Tags: xfce

Is it possible with Xfce 4.8 (Xubuntu 12.04) to have windows minimized on double-clicking the window frames? So, for example, if File Manager is open, to just double-click on the window frame and the the window "disappears" (is minimized to the panel). It would be great if there was a "simple" solution not having to install heavy additional packages.

Comment: the closest I've found is minimize on double-click of the titlebar :( I'm sure there is a solution but I have my doubt that it is "simple".  good luck.

Comment: okay, good to know.

Comment: would just the title bar be good (top of window frame) or do you need it for the rest of the frame (bottom and sides)?

Comment: The title bar would be good! Do you know how this works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XFCE has the ability to minimize the window when double-clicking the window title bar.  I know this is not quite the same as double-clicking the frame, but its very simple without needing further packages or workarounds.

Use Settings --> Window Manager and change the double-click action for the title-bar as shown.

[image]

Comment: *Perfect*, thanks. I completely missed the fact that there is a scroll bar in this window and so I didn't find this menu :-)